# Two functions with same arguments but different return type

Tags: function, typescript, generics

I have a function that takes two functions as arguments (`fn1` and `fn2`). These functions should take the same arbitrary number of arguments with the same types but different return types.

Is there a way to make sure the argument types of the functions are the same?

```js
function myFunction(fn1: Function, fn2: (...args: any[]) => string): number {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any return type? Or two types specified by `myFunction`?

Comment: The return type of the first function can have any type. The return type of the second function is always string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [tuples in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) to extract the arguments types from the first function and specify the second function in terms of the extracted arguments

```
type ArgTypes<T> = T extends (...a:infer A) => unknown?A:[]

function myFunction<T extends (...a: unknown[]) => unknown>(fn1: T, fn2: (...a: ArgTypes<T>) => string) :number {
    return 0;
}

myFunction((s: string) => s, (s:string) => s) //ok
myFunction((s: string) => s, (s:number) => s.toString()) //err
```

Comment: `function myFunction<T extends Function>(fn1: T, fn2: (...a: ArgTypes<T>) => string) :number` should also work

Comment: @dotjpg3141 I avoid using `Function` directly .. but yeah that should also work :)